# Basic JQuery Slider getting stuck on second slide

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I'm trying to fix this slider on my homepage here: example.com.

The slider occasionally works fine, but at least 90% of the time it gets stuck on the second slide (if it makes it past the second slide, it's totally fine). I'd have to guess that the plugin is crashing in some way, because the sliding just isn't working - the images are still there and you can click through them manually.

The original site had lots of extraneous files in the home directory, so I reproduced just the homepage at this URL.

This is actually my first post on StackOverflow and I'm also a beginner at JS, so I'm not sure if this is helpful or not but I'll post the JS code below, despite it being "minimized" and super hard to read.

Thanks for any help!

```
(function(a){a.fn.bjqs=function(b){var c={},d={width:700,height:300,animation:"fade",animationDuration:450,automatic:true,rotationSpeed:4e3,hoverPause:true,showControls:true,centerControls:true,nextText:"Next",prevText:"Prev",showMarkers:true,centerMarkers:true,keyboardNav:true,useCaptions:true},e=this,f=e.find(".bjqs"),g=f.children("li"),h=g.length,i=false,j=false,k=0,l=1,m=0,n=g.eq(k),o="forward",p="backward";c=a.extend({},d,b);g.css({height:c.height,width:c.width});f.css({height:c.height,width:c.width});e.css({height:c.height,width:c.width});g.addClass("bjqs-slide");if(c.showControls&&h>1){var q=a('<ul class="bjqs-controls"></ul>'),r=a('<li><a href="#" class="bjqs-next" class="controls">'+c.nextText+"</a></li>"),s=a('<li><a href="#" class="bjqs-prev" class="controls">'+c.prevText+"</a></li>");r.click(function(a){a.preventDefault();if(!i){A(o,false)}});s.click(function(a){a.preventDefault();if(!i){A(p,false)}});r.appendTo(q);s.appendTo(q);q.appendTo(e);if(c.centerControls){var t=r.children("a"),u=(e.height()-t.height())/2;r.children("a").css("top",u).show();s.children("a").css("top",u).show()}}if(c.showMarkers&&h>1){var v=a('<ol class="bjqs-markers"></ol>'),w,x,u;a.each(g,function(b,d){if(c.animType==="slide"){if(b!==0&&b!==h-1){w=a('<li><a href="#">'+b+"</a></li>")}}else{b++;w=a('<li><a href="#">'+b+"</a></li>")}w.click(function(c){c.preventDefault();if(!a(this).hasClass("active-marker")&&!i){A(false,b)}});w.appendTo(v)});x=v.children("li");x.eq(k).addClass("active-marker");v.appendTo(e);if(c.centerMarkers){u=(c.width-v.width())/2;v.css("left",u)}}if(c.keyboardNav&&h>1){a(document).keyup(function(a){if(!j){clearInterval(z);j=true}if(!i){if(a.keyCode===39){a.preventDefault();A(o,false)}else if(a.keyCode===37){a.preventDefault();A(p,false)}}if(j&c.automatic){z=setInterval(function(){A(o)},c.rotationSpeed);j=false}})}if(c.useCaptions){a.each(g,function(b,c){var d=a(c);var e=d.children("img:first-child");var f=e.attr("title");if(f){var g=a('<p class="bjqs-caption">'+f+"</p>");g.appendTo(d)}})}if(c.hoverPause&&c.automatic){e.hover(function(){if(!j){clearInterval(z);j=true}},function(){if(j){z=setInterval(function(){A(o)},c.rotationSpeed);j=false}})}if(c.animation==="slide"&&h>1){$first=g.eq(0);$last=g.eq(h-1);$first.clone().addClass("clone").removeClass("slide").appendTo(f);$last.clone().addClass("clone").removeClass("slide").prependTo(f);g=f.children("li");h=g.length;$wrapper=a('<div class="bjqs-wrapper"></div>').css({width:c.width,height:c.height,overflow:"hidden",position:"relative"});f.css({width:c.width*h,left:-c.width});g.css({"float":"left",position:"relative",display:"list-item"});$wrapper.prependTo(e);f.appendTo($wrapper)}var y=function(a){if(c.animation==="fade"){if(a===o){!n.next().length?m=0:m++}else if(a===p){!n.prev().length?m=h-1:m--}}if(c.animation==="slide"){if(a===o){m=l+1}if(a===p){m=l-1}}return m};if(c.automatic&&h>1){var z=setInterval(function(){A(o,false)},c.rotationSpeed)}g.eq(k).show();f.show();var A=function(a,b){if(!i){if(a){m=y(a)}else if(b&&c.animation==="fade"){m=b-1}else{m=b}i=true;if(c.animation==="fade"){if(c.showMarkers){x.eq(k).removeClass("active-marker");x.eq(m).addClass("active-marker")}r=g.eq(m);n.fadeOut(c.animationDuration);r.fadeIn(c.animationDuration,function(){n.hide();k=m;n=r;i=false})}else if(c.animation==="slide"){if(c.showMarkers){x.eq(l-1).removeClass("active-marker");if(m===h-1){x.eq(0).addClass("active-marker")}else if(m===0){x.eq(h-3).addClass("active-marker")}else{x.eq(m-1).addClass("active-marker")}}f.animate({left:-m*c.width},c.animationDuration,function(){if(m===0){l=h-2;f.css({left:-l*c.width})}else if(m===h-1){l=1;f.css({left:-c.width})}else{l=m}i=false})}}};return this}})(jQuery)
```

Comment: Looking into it farther, but it seems you're also missing a CSS file "GET http://www.nastynas.com/webfonts/MyFontsWebfontsKit.css 404 (Not Found) " that is the error in the console. - though I don't think this is causing the issue.

Comment: Also, when I try scrolling with the arrows, it seems it's trying to link me to your flavors.php page which apparently is not created.  Another little bug

Comment: The first issue you raise is just because I only brought over the files for the homepage to this sample URL. The second is just bad layout, the link on the squirrel image is slightly too wide to the left. If you are really careful you can click the right slider arrow and avoid that link. Thanks for taking a look! But as you say, I think both are unrelated to the JS slider.

Comment: Whatever is going wrong is pretty difficult to find.  I'm no expert in javascript, though I know my way around.  It seems like the script that you are using is failing after only one turn around.  You might want to get the un-minified version of that script and start placing alerts at different spots in the code.  If the alert doesn't fire - you know there's something wrong around there.

Comment: Where are you initiating the code?  I see that you're linking it, but what is telling the js to work with that element?

Comment: That's some good advice to start troubleshooting, thanks. I'm trying to figure out where it's initiating myself, to be honest. Total JS beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason you're using an old version of jQuery? (version 1.6.2)

That version is more than 2 years out of date - and the bjqs plugin isn't compatible with that version of jQuery.

If there isn't any specific reason you're using this older version, then update to the latest version (http://code.jquery.com/) and the slider will work without any issues. I pulled down the source of your website and tested it locally to confirm.

If you need to keep using 1.6.2 for whatever reason, then unfortunately you'll have to use a different plugin which is compatible with that version of jQuery.

Hope that helps - thanks for using Basic jQuery Slider!

Comment: Thanks so much John! I thought this might be the issue but didn't know how to go about correcting it. I figured it out though, and I'm all set now. Thanks for the great first introduction to using SO!

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SO!

first thing i'd say is http://jsbeautifier.org/ is your friend...it does the opposite of minifying js.

second thing is that even after beautifying the js, it's still pretty hard to follow. in a situation where a plugin/library is buggy, i typically look to replace rather than repair.  have you considered another slideshow plugin such as [Nivo Slider](http://dev7studios.com/plugins/nivo-slider/)? it's available as a jquery plugin for free (don't be mislead by the paid wp plugin), is beautiful, and is easy.

i know this doesn't answer you about what is causing your bug, but hopefully it's a viable workaround!

Comment: Thanks Jon! I did find that website through some Googling, but I wasn't sure how well it worked so just posted the original code. I'll use it in the future! I'll definitely check out Nivo Slider and consider switching it out if I can't get an answer here. Thanks again!